# Validating gridview insert for duplicates

Tags: jquery, asp.net, gridview

I am using a gridview with paging to display a database table.  When the user inserts a UserID, I want to check for duplicates in a custom validate function on the client side.  I have to loop thru all of the values in the grid, not just the ones that are displayed.  I am having trouble getting all of the values in the UserID column to check for the existence of the inserted UserID.
This is the markup:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="UserID">
                <HeaderTemplate> UserID
                     <asp:ImageButton ID="senigvUserIDFilter" runat="server" ImageUrl="Images/filter.png" OnClientClick="return ShowHideFilterTxtBox('senigvTxtUserIDFilter')" />
                    <asp:TextBox ID="senigvTxtUserIDFilter" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" style="display:none;" ClientIDMode="Static" OnTextChanged="senigvGridFilter_TextChanged">
                    </asp:TextBox>
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="senigvLblUserID" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("UserID") %>' ClientIDMode="Static"
                    ></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>   
                    <asp:Label ID="senigvLblEditUserID" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("UserID") %>'></asp:Label>                
                </EditItemTemplate>
                 <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="senigvTxtBxInsertUserID" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("UserID") %>' ClientIDMode="Predictable"></asp:TextBox>      
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="senigvRequiredFieldInsertUserID" ControlToValidate="senigvTxtBxInsertUserID" runat="server"
                        ErrorMessage="Required field." ValidationGroup="InsertSenderValidation" Display="Dynamic" CssClass="message-error">
                    </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>            
                        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="senigvMaxValInsertUserID" ControlToValidate="senigvTxtBxInsertUserID" runat="server"
                        ErrorMessage="Maximumn length is 40." ValidationGroup="InsertSenderValidation" Display="Dynamic" CssClass="message-error"
                        ValidationExpression="^.{1,40}$" >
                    </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                    <asp:CustomValidator ID="senigCustomDupValInsertUserID" runat="server" ControlToValidate="senigvTxtBxInsertUserID" CssClass="message-error" 
                        ErrorMessage="*" ClientValidationFunction="ValidateUserID" EnableClientScript="true" 
                        ValidationGroup="InsertSenderValidation">
                    </asp:CustomValidator>
                 </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

This is the jquery function, 'ValidateUserID'

```
function ValidateUserID(sender, args) {
        args.IsValid = true;
        sender.innerHTML = '';

        var table = document.getElementById("#UserInfoGridVew");
        var tbody = table.tBodies[0];
        //loop thru all UserIDs
        for (i = 0, rowLen = tbody.rows.length; i < rowLen; i++) {
            row = tbody.rows[i];
            var currentUserID = row.cells[1].innerHTML;
            alert('currentUserID: ' + currentUserID);

            if (args.Value == currentUserID) {
                //if values are equal; input invalid; set error message
                args.IsValid = false;
                sender.innerHTML = "UserID exists.";
                break;
            }
        }      
    };
```

When I use this function, I get the error `Object required` on the line `var tbody = table.tBodies[0];`

I need to access all of the data rows in the gridview then check the UserID column for duplicates.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to get all of the data to determine if that is a duplicate is to make a JSON call back to the database and compare values.

The grid uses paging so to get all of the values I had to make a call back to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try below code

```
function ValidateUserID(sender, args) {
    args.IsValid = true;
    sender.innerHTML = '';

var gvDrv = document.getElementById("#UserInfoGridVew");
for (i = 1; i < gvDrv.rows.length; i++) {
var cell = gvDrv.rows[i].cells;
var currentUserID = cell[1].innerHTML;

alert('currentUserID: ' + currentUserID);

  if (args.Value == currentUserID) {
        //if values are equal; input invalid; set error message
       args.IsValid = false;
       sender.innerHTML = "UserID exists.";
       break;
   }

}
}
```

Open the view source of the page and make sure that grid id is "UserInfoGridVew".

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I tried your code and get an error because the `table` variable is null.  The gridview ID has the attribute set to `ClientIDMode='Static'`.  I checked the HTML and script and the id is displayed as 'UserInfoGridView'.

Comment: Oops, got it. When we use javascript we don't add # before the Id. So it should be just document.getElementById('UserInfoGridView');

# before id is added in Jquery.

Comment: Thanks for catching that.  I should have know also.  But the `table` variable only returns 18 rows because that is the size of the page.  I need all of the rows in the datatable.  I tried using `datatable` but the variable is always null.

Comment: You cannot do this in javascript until you have all the date on the client side. When paging is true in grid view, data of only that page is rendered on the browser. And that is not possible with Javascript, unless you use ajax and call a server side function.

Another alternative approach/hack could be that you store all UserIds
into the hiddenfield as JSON format and cross check / compare these
IDs with user input value.

Comment: Yeah.  That is what I found also after doing some research.